# How do I hide a scrollbar using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a lot of content and hence scrolls.. How can I hide the scrollbar such that it is not visible. EDIT: I do want scrolling to work! So.. Scrolling with no scrollbar?

eg

```
.scrolling_div {

     overflow:auto;
     /*something else to hide the scrollbar?*/

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want it to be scrollable without a scrollbar? That's how it came off to me...

Comment: @jay [check my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10405266/297641) and [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y9kDN/2/). Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wrapper which covers the element you want to be scrollable without a scrollbar, and let the wrapper be narrower than the element to scroll, in the horizontal basis. This is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/FlagelloDiDio/EdgTt/

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I spent sometime to write minimal code.

Check [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9kDN/2/). Mouse over the div and scroll to see the scroller.

**Note** that this using an external plugin to listen to [mousewheel event](https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js).

[DEMO page for the plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos)

---

`overflow:hidden` should hide the scrollbar.

```
.scrolling_div {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

overflow can take any one of the below values,

> **visible**
> Default value. Content is not clipped, it may be rendered outside the content box.
>
> **hidden**
> The content is clipped and no scrollbars are provided.
>
> **scroll**
> The content is clipped and desktop browsers use scrollbars, whether or not any content is clipped. This avoids any problem with scrollbars appearing and disappearing in a dynamic environment.Printers may print overflowing content.
>
> **auto**
> Provide scrollbars if content overflows.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 2):

`overflow: auto;` means "show a scrollbar if necessary". Change it to `overflow: hidden;` to disable scrolling.

EDIT: Okay, you want to make a custom scrollbar. Then see [this sample jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/e32pn/) for how to get started - it includes mouse wheeling and dragging of the scrollbar.

Comment: @jay: That's a little difficult, don't you think? How will the user scroll without a scrollbar?

Comment: i know it seems counterintuitive.. you would scroll either with a mouse that is thus enabled, or a custom scroll bar that i designed. this is very much a looks thing..

Comment: @jay You gonna need some javascript if you want to scrolling without default scroll bars.

Comment: @jay: I'm in the process of writing a script now, but tell me in advance if it only has to work on Chrome and Safari - those browsers make it incredibly easy to customize scrollbars.

Comment: hmmm well i'm looking for cross-browser solutions, so if it could be for IE/firefox as well then that would be awesome..

Comment: @jay Do you use any kind of javascript libraries such as jQuery?

Comment: yes i do, jQuery - what about just putting scrolling_list into scrolling_host, give scrolling_list a negative bottom margin - this should work, no?

Comment: @jay: Here's a script I've started. It's not perfect yet, but hopefully you can make it from here. http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/e32pn/

Comment: @minitech I think he want to `EDIT: I do want scrolling to work! So.. Scrolling with no scrollbar?`

Comment: @Vega: Read the earlier comment: *"you would scroll either with a mouse that is thus enabled, or a custom scroll bar that i designed."* And even so, all you have to do is set `display: none` on the scrollbar :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
html {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

it will remove the scrollbar from all the window.

Otherwise if you need it only on a specific div:

```
.scrolling_div {

     overflow: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are going for.  [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

`overflow:hidden;` may be what you want.

If you want to dip into css3, you can play with `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` for even more options.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to hide the scrollbar is to make the content non-scrollable and just cut off if it exceeds the height (`overflow: hidden`). Honestly, why would you want to have a page that is scrollable that doesn't have a scrollbar? That would confuse the heck out of any visitors. There's no way you can do this with CSS.

As far as *customizing* the scrollbar, there are JavaScripts out there to do that. But make sure that if the user has it disabled, they can still properly scroll the page without it.